# How do I set up Openshift Origin router

Tags: openshift-origin

I am trying to stat an Openshift Origin single-node instance on a centos VM.
After installing docker and oc client tools I ran this command:

```
oc cluster up --public-hostanme=MyHostname --routing-suffix=MyHostname.nip.io
```

Everything seems to be working, except when I deploy an app, the router defined for it always routes to nginx welcome page, not my app.
Anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to solved it. I found out that nip.io only works with the server ip, not domain name. I got the routing-suffix to work with the hostname by setting the routing-suffix to MyHostName.dom and adding a wildcard dns record that resolves *.ose-spank.dom to the server ip. (Since I don't have dns server I used Acrylic DNS as a dns proxy)